# Getting the UIKeyboard background color programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikeyboard

Is there any way to get the `UIKeyboard` background color? I am putting an accessory view on top of my `UIKeyboard` and is trying to match its color with the keyboard background color. But, it seems, different types of keyboard has different background colors. Please see below screenshots for default and email keyboard.

Is there any way, we can find out the background color of the keyboard programmatically so that the color of the `accessoryView` could be changed.

[image: UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress]

[image: UIKeyboardTypeDefault]

Comment: find keyWindow, activeView, then got the view of the keyboard, get the color

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
UIKeyboardAppearance currentAppearance = yourTextView.keyboardAppearance;
if (currentAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearanceDark) {
    // dark
}
else if (currentAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault) {
    // default
}
else if (currentAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearanceLight) {
    // light
}
```

Comment: I am using UIKeyboardAppearanceDark all across my app. My problem is that even with the same appearance, different keyboard seems to have different background color.

Comment: It's slightly transparent, could one of your other views be showing behind it, causing the color difference?

Comment: Which one is slightly transparent? second keyboard?

Comment: I'm saying it's possible that both are the same color, but because of transparency, they are showing some of the view below them.  This makes it appear a different color.  Not sure, just trying to troubleshoot.  Are the keyboards displayed on different background colors?

Comment: Kind of but the background view do not differ much.

Comment: How to mitigate the effect of background view just in case its because of this?

Comment: You could use a view to act as background to keyboard view by always displaying it behind it ... if it comes to that.  Perhaps there is a way to get the color programmatically as well.  I am not quite sure, I thought you were looking to distinguish between dark / light, etc.

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 5**

You can use an input view and it matches the keyboard style.

```swift
let textView = UITextView()
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 40)
textView.inputAccessoryView = UIInputView(frame: frame, inputViewStyle: .keyboard)
```

Comment: Do you know how to add a `UIToolbar` inside `UIInputView`? The toolbar doesn't appear if I just do `uiInputView.addSubview(uiToolbar)`

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! never heard of `UIInputView`, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to get your keyboard color's **RGB** from **DigitalColor Meter** as we use this tool in Mac or you can get it by any other tool.

And then simply assign these RGB value to your accessory view and match its color with your keyboard.

The RGB value of your keyboard is seems to me is like `(63,63,63)` and you can use this:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:63/255.0 green:63/255.0 blue:63/255.0 alpha:1]
```

Hopefully it will helps you.

Comment: Yes. Thats what I did. But it seems to work for email keyboard but not for other type of keyboard. Please see the attached screenshots.

Comment: I didn't understand that why is working correctly for the email keyboard and not for other keyboards. I think it should work for all type of keyboard we are only change the background color only.....

Comment: There is no guarantee that color remains unchanged in the future iOS versions, thus hardcoding color values is not the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

For the dark background use

```
 mytextfield.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
```

Comment: Which ios sdk your using... ? Its working perfectly for me..in ios 7

Comment: I am using iOS 7.1 and I think its the background color of the view that is creating the issue, not sure though.

Comment: Don't add any other code to change the background color, I think above single line coding is enough to change the color.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing a custom keyboard and trying to match the background of your keyboard's view, use this in your keyboard's view controller where you set up the view:

```
keyboardView.backgroundColor = view.backgroundColor
```

My `viewDidLoad()` in my keyboard's view controller looks like:

```
var keyboardView: UIView!
let keyboardNib = UINib(nibName: "KeyboardView", bundle: nil)
    keyboardView = keyboardNib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)        
[0] as? UIView
    keyboardView.frame.size = view.frame.size
    keyboardView.backgroundColor = view.backgroundColor
    view.addSubview(keyboardView)
```